# Native for Esperanto "Reprezenti" verb?

Tags: single-word-requests

Esperanto is a language with very strict system of prefixes and suffixes.  *Reprezenti* looks like *re-prezenti*.  But *reprezenti* means "to represent" while *prezenti* means "to attend" or "to be".  Does Esperanto have a verb meaning "to represent" without this confusing (in Esperanto) stem?

Lernu.net points out that *reprezenti* is not *re-prezenti*.

**ADD:**

My question about *re-prezenti* was the question to understand what I want to ask about.  How Esperanto deals with the influence of the national languages?  How new stems are including in Esperanto?  I mean Esperanto has very strict rules that can't be changed by influence of national languages, so every stem must be Esperantized to reflect the idea of simply (but not poor) language.  But the question and answers are already exist: [How often are new loans fully integrated into Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3166/how-often-are-new-loans-fully-integrated-into-esperanto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many instances you can use [*figuri*](http://vortaro.net/#figuri):

> **figuri** (tr)
>   **1** Prezenti, reprodukti formon, figuron de estaĵo aŭ objekto: *la statuo, pentraĵo, bildo figuras personon, leonon, floron, vazon*.
>   **2** Prezenti la aspekton de, roli per sia eksteraĵo: *li ne figuras en tiu filmo*. ☞ [aktori](http://vortaro.net/?w=aktori#aktori), [pozi](http://vortaro.net/?w=pozi#pozi).

—PIV

---

I don't think that *prezenti* means ‘to attend’ or ‘to be’. Where did you find this? It means rather, amongst other things, ‘to present’ (something to others) or ‘to introduce’ (a person to others).

Comment: It's my mistake.  I'm learning Esperanto from Russian, and know something in English.  So to ask this question I need to translate it to English, but the question is about Esperanto! :)  I checked again lernu.net at Russian, there is no such meaning, you're right.

Comment: Ah, that's okay! It did not hinder the question at all either :).

Comment: To the people who downvoted this answer: Please give an explanation as a comment as to why!

Comment: The original question seems to be whether there is a word that means *reprezenti* that doesn't look like *re-prezenti*, and the answer, it seems to me, is plainly "no." *Figuri* is more like "portray" or "depict." Consider also the PIV definitions of *reprezenti*.

Comment: That seems fair enough. There is some small overlap, but you are right that there is no alternative word that works everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to get tired of Esperanto real fast if you don't let go of this concern early. The language is chock full of words which can be misanalyzed (and others which can be broken down even though you don't know it.)

Interestingly enough, the Universala Vortaro lists both *resumo* and *reprezenti* is words built using the prefix *re-*.

From PIV:

> Kvankam la U.V. montras tiun vorton kiel kunmetitaĵon el **re** k **prezent**, la senco estas tiel malproksima de la senco de **prezent**, ke ŝajnas pli ĝuste trakti reprezent kiel apartan rad-on.

As for looking for a different word, don't. If you mean *reprezenti* then say *reprezenti.*

Comment: To this list we can add: *re-formi*.

Answer (score 3):

One of the meanings of *prezenti* is that of *present/introduce someone*:

```
Permesu, ke mi prezentas al vi mian kolegon A.
```

The in Esperanto independant word *reprezenti* more or less means i.a. *act as*, maybe *be an agent for*.

```
Ŝi reprezentis la urbestraron ĉe la kongreso.
```

Both verbs clarifying a role/agency/individual.

That is in far as the meanings relate to each other. The regular word forming in Esperanto might perhaps better have chosen `riprezenti`.

Answer (score 0):

Your might have a look at this [glossary project](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Psychoslave/generic_glossary/eo), which is still in a phase of bilingual lexicon, but which do have some entries for *representation*. Actually if you look up for *present* in the page, you'll find about ten relevant entries.

That doesn't mean that it's a full list of how to translate *representation*, once again it's all about context. So, in which context do you want to use this term?